# CygWin mintty.exe (x64) ends immediately on WIndows 7 (64)

Tags: windows, security, cygwin

After some M$ Windows updates Cygwin mintty (desktop shortcut installed by setup-x86_64.exe) starts but ends immediatelly. I tried to install all missing DLL's which can be observed with dependency walker. I installed 2012 and 2008 Microsoft Redistributable packages which were missed on My Windows 7. I installed both builds (x86 and x64). But it didn't help me to get my CygWin back, because as far as I can see from mintty's logs there is a security issue. I've got a log with the only row:

```
This account is currently not available.
```

I tried to create passwd file with CygWin's mkpasswd and with this command:

```
getent passwd %USERNAME%
```

It didn't help also and I don't have any ideas what to do next.

Now I've got a CygWin installation (Cygwin DLL 2.9.0) with mintty ends immediatelly. I can run Cygwin.bat and use the most of CygWin's functionality, but mintty is more comfortable than M$ Connhost and I want it back.

Comment: Did you reinstall mintty using cygwin setup?

Comment: Mintty is only depending from cygwin dll so you can try to reinstall also that. What is the output of `$ mintty - &` from `cygwin.bat` ?

Comment: `DOMAIN+User(#####)@HOST /cygdrive/d/Projects/XXX`
`$ mintty - &`
`[1] 7476`
``
`DOMAIN+User(#####)@HOST /cygdrive/d/Projects/XXX`
`$`
`[1]+  Done                    mintty -`

Comment: Reinstall attempt was successful but did not help to fix the issue with mintty

Comment: Did you install as an elevated user, and run as an normal user?

Comment: Oops. Did you install `cygwin` as an elevated user, and now want to run `cygwin` as a normal user? Check that your normal user's home directory is owned or `rwx` by that user. On a new `Win10` `cygwin` install, for a user without admin rights, I found I had to change the windows permissions on e.g. `/home/myname` so I could read, write, and execute on that directory. And propagate that to contained files and directories. IIRC, it was not sufficient to do a `chown` and `chmod` while running `cygwin` as my admin user.

Comment: well. I've run setup-x86_64.exe under my current credentials. As far as I can see my account is still a member of the Administrators Windows group. But the results remans the same even with requested elevation.

Answer (score 0):

Something have happened, but today, after an ordinary reboot, mintty begun working.
P.S. It has begun after "**Definition Update for Windows Defender - KB915597 (Definition 1.253.822.0)**" and ended after "**Definition Update for Windows Defender - KB915597 (Definition 1.253.973.0)**".